# AngularJS delay

Tags: angularjs

I mm new to AngularJS. I have the following AngularJS code. I want to add some delay before my redirection code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
if(data.status=='success')
{  
      $scope.succ = "success";
      var sessionid=data.doctor.doctor_id;


     /*------------------------------------*/
     /* How to add delay (3 seconds) here */
     /*------------------------------------*/

  $window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8099/medical-web/login?essionid='+sessionid+'';
```

}

Comment: you can use JS function `setTimeout` for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject `$timeout` in your controller and write something like

```
$timeout(function() {
   $window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8099/medical-web/login?essionid='+sessionid+'';
}, 3000);
```

Comment: @Prashanth if so, please accept the answer

Comment: @Prashanth just click the check below an answer to accept it